# T-SQL Group by When empty ResultSet

Tags: sql, t-sql

how can select count in group by when empty ResultSet and part record

Table T schema is
column A int,column B int

data demo A is

```
A    B
1    11
1    2
1    Null
2    1
2    21
3    12
3    Null
```

data demo B is

```
A    B
2    1
2    21
3    12
3    Null
4    11
4    2
4    Null
```

data demo C is

```
A    B
(empty record)
```

I want select to this ResultSet

```
A    B
1    Bcount
2    Bcount
3    Bcount
4    Bcount
```

my sql code is

```
select A,Count(B) FROM T
group by A
```

when data demo A I lost A=4 result

when data demo B I lost A=1 result

when data demo C I lost all result,ResultSet is empty.

Comment: Create a dimension table that always contains all the entities that you need to report on, then use `SELECT dimension.A, COUNT(data.B) FROM dimension LEFT JOIN data ON data.A = dimension.A GROUP BY dimension.A`

Comment: Are your search values always 1,2,3,4 ?  You need a separate table to define the search values.

If you have an empty table or a value is missing, SQL cannot guess what the missing data is.

Comment: what values for `Bcount` do you expect for A = 1, 2, 3 & 4 with your data ?

Comment: yes，I always search A＝1,2,3,4

Comment: @ian-kenney Yes,always search A=1,2,3,4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is still unclear, but maybe you are after something like

```
select v.A, count(t.b)
from (select 1 as A union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) as v 
left join t on t.a = v.a 
group by 1
```

Comment: Prefect code. Thank you for answer,group by 1 change to group by v.A is OK.

Answer (score 1):

You can left join to VALUES

```
SELECT V.A, COUNT(T.B) AS Total_B
FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)) V(A)
LEFT JOIN T ON (T.A = V.A) 
GROUP BY V.A
ORDER BY V.A;
```

Or create a reference table for the values of A.
Then left join to the reference table.

```
CREATE TABLE REF_A (A INT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO REF_A (A) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4);

SELECT A.A, COUNT(T.B) AS Total_B
FROM REF_A A
LEFT JOIN T ON (T.A = A.A) 
GROUP BY A.A
ORDER BY A.A;
```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=5daf047ed78ee34499ecbaf75b7e0863)*

Comment: Thank you for answer,Ian Kenney is solve my problem,and you code is very graceful.